# Facing Assertion failed: (thread_id_key != 0x7777), function find_thread_id_key, file ../src/coroutine.cc, line 134 when I do npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, assertion, npm-start

When I did npm login, Got ERR! Code 426. So did

$npm cache clean --force

$rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

$npm install

npm install did succeed with 200 OK.

When I do npm start, facing assertion failed(v16). When I googled it's asking to install earlier versions of node.js. I tried installing v14 - couldn't locate the .npmrc file and adding it didn't work. I tried installing v12 - Apple is not allowing to install & asking to install the later version. So any help would be appreciated.

[1] depict npm login error [2] depict assertion failed error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPNrt.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUms0.png

Answer (score 1):

Probably an issue with fibres in Node ^16.x, try :

```
npm uninstall fibers && rm package-lock.json && rm -R node_modules && npm install
```

Comment: I did this, still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, This works for me 'npm uninstall fibers && rm package-lock.json && rm -R node_modules && npm install'